# Run a command on a list of files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

The command `shred` in ubuntu does not shreds files recursively. Hence, I wanted to list all the files in a directory by doing `find -L` and then shred these files using `shred`.
However, `find -L | shred` does not works. Can someone please help me do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into the `-execdir` option to `find`.

Comment: @ShawnBrar : Your `find` also crawls through all subdirectories for shredding, following symlinks. Place - by mistake - a symlink to `/` in one of the subdirectories, and you shred all files on your filesystem where you have write permission.

Comment: @ShawnBar : See the option `-exec` to `find`. You also will likely have to use `-type f` in your `find` command.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this even related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find | shred` works as if you ran just `shred` and then started typing the paths to be shredded into the terminal. But `shred` does not care about stdin. It only shreds paths given as arguments.

To pass the paths printed by `find` as arguments to another program you can use `xargs`, or better `find -exec`.

Here we also only shred files, as `shred someDirectory` will just print an error.

```
find -L -type f -exec shred {} +
```

**Reminder:** Depending on your file system and hardware `shred` might not overwrite the physical original. Especially file systems like Btrfs with its CoW mechanism and SSDs with their wear leveling are problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get them done in parallel very simply with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
find -L -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -X shred
```